# Visual Studio 2005 hanging when debugging javascript, with a Delay Notification

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I am working on Windows XP with Visual Studio 2005 and IE8.

Whenever I am trying javascript debugging in VS2005, it's working for a while, and then at some point (randomly) it hangs and gives me the following Delay Notification:

"Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an operation to complete. If you regularly encounter this delay during normal usage please report this problem to Microsoft. Please include a description of the work you were doing in Microsoft Visual Studio and when possible instruction on how to reproduce this delay.

If Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting on another application you can switch to that application now, or you can continue waiting for this operation to complete."
[Switch to...] [Continue Waiting] [*Cancel Operation*]

Then, if I press the first two buttons, the dialog disappears until I click anywhere on VS2005. The third button is disabled.

The only thing I can do is restart VS and then everything is fine.

Comment: Any chance of upgrading to a version of VS that is less than 6 years old?

Comment: @Matt-Ball, I would if it was up to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The IE9 built-in debugger is a far better tool than the one in VS2005.

Comment: Working on XP and IE9 doesn't run on XP :(

Comment: The same goes for the IE8 built-in debugger. I abandoned the VS JavaScript debugger long ago.